# Последовательное выполнение js функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Приветствую.
Прошу сразу не пинать, я в js полный ноль но задачу надо решить, с вашей помощью будет быстрее.
И так сам вопрос как выполнить последовательное выполнение не скольких функции подряд, или может быть есть другое решение я буду только рад.

**Часть кода**

```html
<span id="true-random-integer-generator-max-button-span">
<input type="button" value="Generate" name="true-random-integer-generator-button" id="true-random-integer-generator-button" onclick="getTrueRandomInteger(document.getElementById('true-random-integer-generator-min').value, document.getElementById('true-random-integer-generator-max').value);" />
</span>
<label for="true-random-integer-generator-result">Result:</label>
```

Тут как я понимаю и вызывается функция **printNumber()**

```js
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        var waitremain = 600 - (new Date().getTime() - begin);
        if (waitremain > 0) {
            setTimeout(printNumber, waitremain);
        } else {
            printNumber();
                        printNumber1();
        }
    }
}
function printNumber() {
    var trngresponse = 55; //Сюда вставить нужно число  
    document.getElementById("true-random-integer-generator-result").innerHTML = trngresponse;
}
```

Тут я тупо  скопировал, и думал можно их последовательно вызвать но нет не получилось.

```js
function printNumber1() {
var trngresponse = 11; //Сюда вставить нужно число  
document.getElementById("true-random-integer-generator-result").innerHTML = trngresponse;
}
```

Данная функция выводит на страницу число, результат должен быть такой.
Пользователь нажимает кнопку 1 раз выводиться 1 число указанное в переменной **trngresponse**
потом нажимает 2 раз выводится на страницу уже другое число которые тоже должно быть указанно в этой же переменной **trngresponse**.
И так несколько раз нажимает появляются те числа что указанны в переменной **trngresponse**

Или это можно как-то решить через массивы привязанные к индексу и потом перебирать их и они будут вызываться на странице.
Прошу прощения за корявое разъяснение js для меня не подъемный язык

P.S. так понимаю тут используется GetXmlHttpObject 
не знаю важно ли это или нет.

---

Часть задачи уже помогли решить, остался вопрос как прикрутить к событию onclick  а именно к кнопки button последовательное отображение чисел.

---

Предыдущий вариант от **@Igor** почти похож с тем что должно получиться, только последовательность зависит от нажатие кнопки Generate.
Каждое нажатие кнопки Generate формирует число заранее указанное в переменной.

Еще Добавлю от себя, как это будет выглядеть в итоге.
Заходим на сайт random который скопированный на локальный сервер, 
указываем числа min и max толку от них нету это просто для видимости.

Жмем кнопку Generate бац появляется число которое заранее указанно в переменной.
Жмем кнопку Generate еще раз появляется другое число которое ранее было указанно в скрипте и так не сколько раз последовательно, так понимаю нужен массив любых чисел [52,22,78,58] и т.д.

По сути мы жмем кнопку генерировать для видимости, но числа показывает те которые ранее указали в скрипте.
Так же основной задачей является сохранить полноценный сайт random  со всякими гифками и ajax-loader.gif. 
По этому приходится делать правки именно в файле iframe.js, изначально и показал то место где формируется результат и он показывается на главной.

P.S. Прошу прощения, что заставляю ломать мозг что бы понять что я хочу получить в итоге, крайне сложно изложить свою матрицу из головы в сообщение но я буду стараться.

Comment: Ваш вопрос находи**Ь**тся за пределами моего понимания, но я чувствую, что он очень мощный и симпатичный.

Comment: А можно  по делу отвечать

Comment: По делу отвечать нельзя, потому что я не понимаю, в чем дело. А если я не понимаю, в чем тут дело, то, с большой вероятностью, никто не поймет.

Comment: @Igor и что делать? архив прикрепил там все файлы

Comment: Вам генератор случайных чисел надо написать что-ль? Чтобы по нажатию на кнопку случайное число генерировалось и записывалось в тег label?

Comment: По нажатию кнопки, в результат попадает то  число что указанно в переменной в функции printNumber() и так не сколько раз подряд.

Comment: 1 раз нажал число 54 
2 раз нажал число 44
3 раз .... Но эти числа указанны заранее в файл js надо сделать копию сайта random.org такой вот запрос поступил

Comment: вы шлете запрос, на получение рандомного числа, но с результатом ничего не делаете, сделайте переменную `trngresponse` глобальной и пишите в нее результат запроса и все

Comment: В том то вся задача, надо что бы последовательно шли числа ранее указанные в переменной или переменных,  без дополнительных правок в коде.

Comment: без дополнительных правок в коде все будет работать точь в точь как раньше

Comment: Я так понял что вам необходимо сделать (слямзить) генератор случайных чисел с random.org, но не могу понять почему вы не можете написать точно такой же свой генератор с интервалом от min до max.

Comment: @Andrew, ты написал два ответа, которые ответами не являются, если хочешь внести поправку в вопрос, нажми под вопросом кнопку  ПРАВИТЬ, и дополни вопрос или объясни в комментарии, твои ответы будут удалены и если ты хочешь, что бы эта информация осталась, то перенеси ее сам в свой вопрос...

Comment: Здравствуйте. Весь нужный код должен быть в вопросе. В архивах на гуглдрайве — нельзя, таковы правила сайта.

Comment: @Andrew У Вас есть массив чисел, из которого по клику надо брать один элемент и показывать пользователю, так? Брать надо по порядку или случайно?

Comment: @Igor брать числа надо строго по порядку. [10,55,90] - жмем кнопку берем число 10,  потом еще раз жмем берем 55 и выводим на страницу. И так до конца массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Естественно, никакой архив с гугл драйва я открывать не буду. Вот то, что Вам надо. Если это не то, что Вам надо, объясняйте, что Вам надо так, чтобы Вас поняли.

```js
var values = [1,2,3,4,5];

setInterval(function(){
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
  document.getElementById("display").innerText = values[index];
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="display"></span>
```

*Update*

Вот - с кликом:

```js
function nextNumber() {
  var values = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var index = this.currentIndex;
  if (!index)
    index = 0;
  document.getElementById("display").innerText = values[index];
  if (index >= values.length - 1)
    index = -1;
  this.currentIndex = index + 1; 
}
```

```css
#display
{
  border:1px black solid;
  padding:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="nextNumber()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Так получилось найти решение ?

Comment: Все отлично именно то что нужно,  маленький штрих когда массив заканчивается выскакивает - **undefined**  как это победить? Например пусть  сбрасывает index на ноль и начинается сначала ?

Comment: @Andrew Минуту, Вы точно весь код скопировали? У меня-то не выскакивает - `if (index >= values.length - 1) ...`

Comment: да вы правы, не внимательность.  Огромное вас спасибо.

Comment: @Andrew На здоровье. Рад, что все так хорошо закончилось, несмотря на небольшое непонимание вначале. Успехов.